# How to Pop up checkout when add to cart click?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Want to ask if there is any way to code the pop up checkout of the woo commerce check out,

[image]

here the screen shot when the user click the add to cart the check out would be pop up to show the product

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I try to achieve the exact same thing.

Comment: I managed to display the checkout form from anywhere with echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]'). Now the problem is that the payment methods (which are Ajax-loaded in WooCommerce) are missing. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Rather than using a bounty on this very poor, off-topic question, I recommend asking a new one. Be sure to include any code you have written in your attempt to achieve this goal.

Comment: This is a very difficult thing to solve.  I would suggest that it's NOT a good way to go, because the WooCommerce checkout is highly AJAXy, and it's tricky (at best) to get AJAX within an AJAX to work properly, *particularly when the system was not engineered that way to begin with*.  Also, this would likely end up being fairly brittle, because WooCommerce gets upgraded often, and those upgrades often include changes to cart / checkout that could end up "breaking" any solution you came up with.  **Put another way: There's a reason WooCommerce doesn't offer this already**.

Comment: Thanks @cale_b. Actually I'm loading the checkout form through Ajax. It is merely display in a lightbox by clicking a button, but it is already generated in the DOM when page loads. So there won't be Ajax within Ajax.

Comment: I agree with rnevius. You'd be better off writing your own, significantly more detailed, question. Especially if you've already got a partial attempt that you can share. You're question then comes off as a specific coding question and not a plea for free coding.

Comment: Or just edit the question with the code you have already tried. Have you also reached out to the folks at woo? Maybe there is a hook for this.

Comment: It's actually doable by loading the checkout page in an iframe (with a custom page template that has no header or footer).