# Add to cart pop up when specific items are added to cart (cs-cart)

Tags: php, cs-cart

I am new to cs-cart. Not really familiar with it. My latest project involves working with Cs-Cart. I have been able to work out how to output products and to work with categories.

Been trying this for a few weeks now. Been on few websites and stackoverflow questions. Nothing quite like what I want. [The only S.O. question that came close has no answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803060/how-to-pop-up-checkout-when-add-to-cart-click)

I will like to have a little pop up when an item a specific item is added to the cart. In the popup div or box, I will like to suggest other items with. If possible with an add to cart button next to each suggestion.
I have searched everywhere but not much. I don't mind creating my own plugin for this but I don't know how to listen to those add to cart events and creating popups in cs-cart.

Any help is appreciated ..

Answer (score 0):

If you add a product to cart in CS-Cart, you have a pop-up box. By default, the add to cart function is done via AJAX request.
If you would like to modify this notification's content, you have to check the `/design/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/views/checkout/components/product_notification.tpl` template file. (replace the YOUR_THEME_NAME)

However I suggest you, not to write directly into a core file (both php and tpl files). You can find the [official developer documentation here](http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.2.x/).

If you would like to create a controller extension for the add to cart function, you can create a controller eg. /app/addons/my_changes/controllers/frontend/checkout.post.php. Write this code into this file:

```
<?php

if ($mode == "add") {
    //Do something here
}
```

If the My changes add-on is active, this code will run after the product is added to the cart, but before the tpl file is displayed.

Comment: your solution is a good one. I just finished creating my addon. need to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the **app/addons/my_changes/controllers/frontend/checkout.post.php** file with the following content:

```php
<?php

use Tygh\Registry;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if ($mode == 'add') {
      $added_products = Registry::get('view')->getTemplateVars('added_products');
      if (!empty($added_products)) {
        foreach ($added_products as $data) {
          if (!empty($data['product_id']) && $data['product_id'] == THE_ID_OF_REQUIRED_PRODUCT) {
             $msg = Registry::get('view')->fetch('addons/my_changes/custom_product_notification.tpl');
             fn_set_notification('I', __('custom_product_notification_title'), $msg, 'I');
          }
        }
      }
   }
  return;
}
```

then

- create the "custom_product_notification_title" language variable on the Administration -> Language -> Manage translation page
- create the "design/themes/YOUR_THEME/templates/addons/my_changes/custom_product_notification.tpl" template with the required content
- activate the "My changes" add-on
- clear the cache by adding the "?cc&ctpl" to the URL in the admin panel